# Coding a PHP Single Sign On Similar to godaddy

Tags: php

As you can see when signing into Godaddy, they have implemented a single sign on system that logs you into multiple subdomains on their website.  The url changes and as it changes, it logs you into each one, then comes back to the original one that you were logging into.

With that being said...

1) I'm assuming they are passing variables via POST when form is submitted, then resubmitting form data to the other domain via POST, then again, and again...etc...  Is this correct?

2) They are passing them across 1 top level domain.  Is it possible to pass these variables (like they are) to a new domain all together.  **Example:** Log into domain1.com, and then it changes to domains2.com and logs you in there, and then domain3.com, etc. (down a predefined list)

3) Are there any better options than the way they are doing it that would work better for my project (listed below)?

My project:

I am working on a project that has a few domains, and will expand in the future to include more domains.  I am trying to come up with a method that when the user logs into one, it will somehow log them into all of them. This will allow the user to be able to go between the sites and remain logged in without having to relogin to each domain.  It is all using 1 users database and then each site has its own databases as well.  Right now, the domains are all on 1 servers; however, eventually, each domain will have its own server.

I'm doing this as a learning experience because I've always been intrigued by SSO as well as trying to get this to work in a production environment if I can manage to get it to work efficiently.

Any recommendations/suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is that you can place a web element on both domains that can be pulled from another domain. You can then use the URL to notify the other domain that a user is on the first domain. This can then allow domain B to associate that user ID with that user on their system. Kind of hard to explain, but I hope you get the point; how you would actually like to code the logic behind that would be up to you as there are many ways of doing so.

Be sure to note, that if you are using this (or any other method for that matter) you should first wrap your head around the inherent risks present if you don't user proper encryption and authentication, etc. I'd advise you to do some research on protecting against attacks such as "man in the middle" or "replaying". Since you own both domains, however, you should have no problem setting a secure secret key for both.

You can also check out this site that has a walk through for sharing the same cookie across multiple domains:
http://www.15seconds.com/issue/971108.htm

Comment: The link you shared.  I noticed that they were using slave.asp.  Is the code actually in asp?  Or is that php?

Comment: That code is actually written in asp but the same principles apply. I was using that example to demonstrate the theory rather than provide a step by step walk through. Do you understand the concept? Or is there something you would like me to clarify or demonstrate? Let me know what you do understand and we can work from there.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the setup was a little strange to be php but I did have to ask.  Umm, I actually don't know ASP at all.  And I'm unfamiliar about how to setup a SSO system in php really which is why I'm looking into it.  I like how they are doing it...If I'm not mistaking.  They sign into site 1.  When they get to site 2...it automatically checks site 1 to see if they are logged in, then brings them back to site 1 with some kind of user identification, and then it logs them into site2.  But thats about all I got out of it.

Comment: I think before you're going to be able to code this, you're going to need to do some research first. This is a very good article that outlines the theory behind the process and also has a downloadable example coded in PHP. With something like this, just make sure you understand the security risks with each step before implementing anything on a live server. When you've got your head around things, you can open a more specific question to help you out along the way.

Comment: See info here: http://www.jasny.net/articles/simple-single-sign-on-for-php/